# Can I say: Technology has a word to say?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing an essay on how technology has affected our lives and I would like to know if I can say "Technology has a word to say when it comes to communication". for example.

What I would like to say is that technology has an impact but I'm not sure if it is right..
Thank you in advance

Comment: As long as you follow up with, "And that word is..." ;-)

Comment: sure u cud say dat

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can say that, if the intent is that technology has an impact on or addresses issues related to communication.

Answer (score 0):

You can!

*Somebody/thing has a word to say* is a way of telling that there's *broadly* a role of somebody/thing in that or if it is some person, s/he wants to tell us something.

However, I *observe* that it is used more in negation such as [*Nobody found a word to say*](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/wires/pa/article-2762135/Wenger-leaps-Ozils-defence.html) or *[No history has a word to say](http://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/1315615-a-room-of-one-s-own).*

Clearly, in all these examples, we are not talking about ***one particular word*** but talking in general that they have/don't have something/anything to say.

I use it often in conferences and meetings.

> Before we begin the session, our CEO has a word to say.

Of course, CEO would speak more than a word! :)